# Insert data in a different table sql/ php

Tags: php, mysql

Could you please help me
i have two different tables

**table tbl_users:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prenom` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adresse` varchar(100)  DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10)  DEFAULT NULL,
  `roleid` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isActive` tinyint(4) DEFAULT 0,
  `idjob`int(11),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

**table travail:**

```
create table `travail`(
`id`int(11) NOT NULL,
`job` varchar(200) Default ' ' NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

I put `idjob` as a foreign key .*

And I want to insert the value of job in the user table and i don' know how

the following code of "job" section

**register.php**:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <ul>
        <li> 
            <label >
                <input type="radio" name="job" value="traiteur" checked/>
                <img  class="imag" src="../img/traite.png" />
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="job" value="cuisinier"  />
                <img src="../img/cui.png" />
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="job" value="patissier" />
                <img src="../img/patis.png" />
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="job" value="stylistcheveux"  />
                <img src="../img/ha.webp" />
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="job" value="makeupartist"  />
                <img src="../img/make.png" />
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>

            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="job" value="stylistvetements" />
                <img src="../img/stv.png" />
            </label>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label >
                <input type="radio" name="job" value="photographe" />
                <img src="../img/ph.png" />
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label >
                <input type="radio"  name="job" value="musicien" />
                <img src="../img/d.png" />
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label >
                <input type="radio" name="job" value="dj"  />
                <img src="../img/dj.png" />
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" name="register" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
</div>
```

**Users.php:**

```
// User Registration Method
public function userRegistration($data){
    $name = $data['name'];
    $username = $data['username'];
    $email = $data['email'];
    $mobile = $data['mobile'];
    $prenom = $data['prenom'];
    $roleid = $data['roleid'];
    $password = $data['password'];

    $checkEmail = $this->checkExistEmail($email);

    if ($name == "" || $username == "" || $email == "" || $mobile == "" || $password == "" ) {
      $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible mt-3" id="flash-msg">
<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
<strong>Error !</strong> Please, User Registration field must not be Empty !</div>';
        return $msg;
    }elseif (strlen($username) < 3) {
      $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible mt-3" id="flash-msg">
<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
<strong>Error !</strong> Username is too short, at least 3 Characters !</div>';
        return $msg;
    }elseif (filter_var($mobile,FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) == FALSE) {
      $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible mt-3" id="flash-msg">
<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
<strong>Error !</strong> Enter only Number Characters for Mobile number field !</div>';
        return $msg;

    }elseif(strlen($password) < 5) {
      $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible mt-3" id="flash-msg">
<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
<strong>Error !</strong> Password at least 6 Characters !</div>';
        return $msg;
    }elseif(!preg_match("#[0-9]+#",$password)) {
      $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible mt-3" id="flash-msg">
<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
<strong>Error !</strong> Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Number !</div>';
        return $msg;
    }elseif(!preg_match("#[a-z]+#",$password)) {
      $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible mt-3" id="flash-msg">
<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
<strong>Error !</strong> Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Number !</div>';
        return $msg;
    }elseif (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL === FALSE)) {
      $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible mt-3" id="flash-msg">
<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
<strong>Error !</strong> Invalid email address !</div>';
        return $msg;
    }elseif ($checkEmail == TRUE) {
      $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible mt-3" id="flash-msg">
<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
<strong>Error !</strong> Email already Exists, please try another Email... !</div>';
        return $msg;
    }else{

      $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_users(name, username, email, password, mobile,prenom,roleid) VALUES(:name, :username, :email, :password, :mobile,:prenom, :roleid)";
      $stmt = $this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindValue(':name', $name);
      $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
      $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
      $stmt->bindValue(':password', SHA1($password));
      $stmt->bindValue(':mobile', $mobile);
      $stmt->bindValue(':prenom', $prenom);

      $stmt->bindValue(':roleid', $roleid);
      $result = $stmt->execute();
      if ($result) {
        $msg = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible mt-3" id="flash-msg">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
            <strong>Success !</strong> Wow, you have Registered Successfully !</div>';
        return $msg;
    }else{
        $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible mt-3" id="flash-msg">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
            <strong>Error !</strong> Something went Wrong !</div>';
        return $msg;
    }
```

Comment: Based on the syntax, I have made the assumption this is MySQL, *not* SQL Server.

Comment: It does not make sense to do that, store it as a string in the user table, it's user input after all. Having to check if that job already exist, and add it to the job table is cumbersome

Comment: Also worth noting is that you should use `password_hash` and password_verify` to deal with the hashing and validating of a user's password rather than rely upon weak hashes such as `sha1` or `md5` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your register.php, it would be way more practical to have the ids of the jobs as values instead of having the names of the jobs. Then you can just plug that number in the insert just like you're plugging in name and everything else. You can surround your input with labels instead of putting the names of the jobs in the value, like this:

```
<label><input type=radio name=job value=0> Cook</label>
<label><input type=radio name=job value=1> Driver</label>
<label><input type=radio name=job value=2> Superhero</label>
```

Then you do the validation of the field on the php side, like you're doing to all other fields and add it to the query. The FK is just a regular field.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_users(name, username, email, password, mobile,prenom,roleid) VALUES(:name, :username, :email, :password, :mobile,:prenom, :roleid, :jobid)";
$stmt = $this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindValue(':password', SHA1($password));
$stmt->bindValue(':mobile', $mobile);
$stmt->bindValue(':prenom', $prenom);

$stmt->bindValue(':roleid', $roleid);
$stmt->bindValue(':jobid', $jobid);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: thank u so much , I did it and it display the id value but how can i display the name of the job

Comment: You either do a SELECT with JOIN...ON between the tables or do 2 SELECTs one for the user and the other for the jobs. Which one is the best depends on what you're doing.

The following query would do what you want:
`SELECT u.name as user_name, j.name as job_name FROM tbl_users u JOIN tbl_jobs j ON (u.jobid = j.id) WHERE u.id = :userid`

You can adapt that to your use-case